# Django channels group_send not working properly

Tags: django, django-channels

I was trying to implement a bidding module with django-channels. Basically I broadcast any message I received from clients, and my consumer part goes as the following code snippet:

```py
class BidderConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        print("Connected")
        await self.accept()
        # Add to group
        self.channel_layer.group_add("bidding", self.channel_name)
        # Add channel to group
        await self.send_json({"msg_type": "connected"})

    async def receive_json(self, content, **kwargs):
        price = int(content.get("price"))
        item_id = int(content.get("item_id"))
        print("receive price ", price)
        print("receive item_id ", item_id)
        if not price or not item_id:
            await self.send_json({"error": "invalid argument"})

        item = await get_item(item_id)
        # Update bidding price
        if price > item.price:
            item.price = price
            await save_item(item)
            # Broadcast new bidding price
            print("performing group send")
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                "bidding",
                {
                    "type": "update.price"
                    "price": price,
                    "item_id": item_id
                }
            )

    async def update_price(self, event):
        print("sending new price")
        await self.send_json({
            "msg_type": "update",
            "item_id": event["item_id"],
            "price": event["price"],
        })
```

But when I attempted to update the price from browser, the consumer could received the message from it however it could not successfully call the `update_price` function. (`sending new price` was never printed):

```
receive price  701
receive item_id  2
performing group send
```

I was just following this example:
https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/tree/master/multichat

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it print "performing group send"?

Comment: @mehamasum Thanks for asking, yes it printed "performing group send"

Comment: dont give await in group send

Comment: @MohitHarshan I tried to delete await in group_send but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Is your channel layer up and running? https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html#enable-a-channel-layer

Comment: I resolved this problem... I was stupid enough to miss the `await` when I perform `group_add`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, change from this:

```
await self.channel_layer.group_send(
    "bidding",
    {
        "type": "update.price"
         "price": price,
         "item_id": item_id
    }
)
```

to this:

```
await self.channel_layer.group_send(
     "bidding",
     {
         "type": "update_price"
         "price": price,
         "item_id": item_id
     }
)
```

Notice the underscore in the `type` key. Your function is called `update_price`, so the type needs to be the same.

Comment: Actually, the channel layer converts the dot to underscore before calling. Types like webscoket.connect become webscoket_connect. It's just more clear in the protocol level using the dot notation but either can be used. Check the examples in the docs and see that they also use the dot notation

Answer (score -1):

This might help you:
Inside routing.py try `path("", MainConsumer.as_asgi())` instead of `path("", MainConsumer)`.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. You can try to allocate a separate redis database for channels_layer. This is done by adding the redis database number after its port + `'/{number_of_database}'`

Seems like that `'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/1'`

By default, Redis instances have 16 databases (numbered 0 to 15), but this can be configured in the Redis configuration file. Each database is a separate namespace that can hold its own set of keys and values.

Note that when using Redis databases in a production environment, it's a good practice to separate different types of data into separate databases or even separate Redis instances to avoid conflicts and improve performance.

In settings.py

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": ['redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/1'],
        },
    },
}
```